# How to scope create method in Rails using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am having a problem with saving form data and including the correct account_id. The form below shows when the current_user.account_id does have a record in the dataload_mailchimps table. If the visitor adds their api key to the form, it should be saved into the dataload_mailchimps table along with the account_id of the current_user.

However, right now the api_key is saved correctly no account_id is saved to the dataload_mailchimps table. What should I be doing differently to save current_user.account_id into the table when the form is submitted?

My controller:

```
class DataloadMailchimpsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @dataload = DataloadMailchimp.new(params[:dataload_mailchimp].merge(
        account_id: current_user.account_id )
    )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @dataload.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_dataload_mailchimp_path, notice: 'Dataload mailchimp was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @dataload, status: :created, location: @dataload }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @dataload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The form (_form.html.haml):

```
= form_for @dataload, :url => dataload_mailchimp_path do |f|
  .fieldset
    .field
      = f.label :api_key
      %br/
      = f.text_field :api_key

  - if @dataload.new_record? || @dataload.api_key.blank?
    %p Please specify Mailchimp API key for additional configuration

  .actions
    = f.submit 'Update Mailchimp Dataload'
```

Comment: are you using attribute_accessible stuff? is `account_id` allowed in there? did you try setting it directly? `@dataload.account =  current_user.account`?

Comment: @phoet your suggestions were right on. Thanks for your help. I added :account_id to attr_accessible and separated the account_id assignment and it worked. Do you want to add your suggestions as an answer and I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to have :account_id in your `attr_accessible` then you should add the account directly:

```
@dataload.account = current_user.account
```